# Check a c file output in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have 2 files .c which only contain a printf("x")
I am in bash script and i want to check if the values in the printf are for project1.c =20 and for project 2 =10,and then make some changes depending on the values.
How am i supposed to make the comparison in the if command?
This is what i have tried to do,not sure if it is right way.

```
for d in $1/*/*

do
gcc project1 project1.c 
if[ ./project1 = 20 ];then
$project1 =30
else
$project1 =0
fi
gcc project2 project2.c
if[ ./project2 =10 ];then
$project2 = 70
else
$project2 = 0
fi
sum=$project1 + $project2
echo "project1 : $project1 project2: $project2 total grade: $sum" >> grades.txt

done
fi
```

Comment: `printf("x")` will just print `x`, how can that ever be `20` or `10`?

Comment: Use `"$(./project1)"` to get the output of the program as a string.

Comment: You need to learn basic shell syntax. You need space between `if` and `[`. You can't have spaces around `=` in an assignment. You don't put `$` before the variable you're assigning to.

Comment: Paste your code into shellcheck.net, it will show all the obvious problems.

Comment: printf("x") is mainly because the values in the .c files differ,so you just assume that the x is a value and i want to check whether it is 20 or not.
Regarding the shell syntax,thanks for the advice,i will apply them later on to my code and change it,i hope i can count on you if i come accross any more difficulties!thanks!

Comment: It wasn't obvious that you meant `x` as a placeholder there.

Answer (score 0):

Your invocation of `gcc` is wrong. You have to specify the output file:

```
gcc -o project1 project1.c
```

Next, in shell, variable substitution is a different process than assignment. So, you can't write `$var=foo`. The correct syntax is `var=foo`.

Then, space is a special character (it is used to separate arguments). So `var=foo` is not the same than `var = foo`. So, the correct syntax is:

```
project1=30
```

Next, in shell, the pattern `$(command)` is replaced by the result of `command`. So. I have to do:

```
if [ $(./project2) == 10 ]; then
```

Finally, you can do arithmetic using `$((calculus))`. So, you have to write:

```
sum=$(($project1 + $project2))
```

Comment: BTW, please indent/clean-up your code before to publish it.

Comment: i am new in the linux environment and it is kinda different than all the other programming stuff i ve seen,therefore i suck at it :D 
thanks for the tips and the solutions,i will apply them later and tell you if i have any other difficulties!